# add subview to collectionview cell jsqmessagesviewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I'm trying to add a subview to each cell (message) of my collectionView (`JSQMessagesViewController`) to display time of my message, something like this:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = super.collectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAt: indexPath) as! JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell

        let message = messages[indexPath.item]

        let timeLabel = UILabel()
        timeLabel.frame = cell.textView.frame
        timeLabel.text = "abc"
        timeLabel.textColor = .blue

        cell.addSubview(timeLabel)

        if message.senderId == senderId { // 1
            cell.textView?.textColor = UIColor.black // 3
            cell.avatarImageView.image = self.avatars.0.image
            cell.avatarImageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.avatarImageView.frame.size.height / 2
            cell.avatarImageView.clipsToBounds = true
        } else {

            cell.textView?.textColor = UIColor.black // 2
            cell.avatarImageView.image = self.avatars.1.image
            cell.avatarImageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.avatarImageView.frame.size.height / 2
            cell.avatarImageView.clipsToBounds = true

        }

        return cell
    }
```

But it adds me 2 labels:

[image]

Why there are 2 labels? And how can I add this label particularly to the bottom-right of my message? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Check `JSQMessagesCollectionViewCellIncoming.nib` and `JSQMessagesCollectionViewCellIncoming.nib` and adjust the `Cell bottom label` as per your need to make it look like your design.Adjust Autolayout constraint and done.

[image]

Comment: could you give me an example please, how should I set my constraints to place this lable at bottom-right of my msg? I've tried a lot but label still at the bottom

Answer (score 1):

**Problem 1**

Basically, you are creating every time new instance of label.

```
let timeLabel = UILabel()
timeLabel.frame = cell.textView.frame
timeLabel.text = "abc"
timeLabel.textColor = .blue
```

Due to the concept of reuses, the cell will reuse everything for the next time. So when you add the subview of `timeLabel` for the first time that is ready to reuse for the next time. and you are adding again it `let timeLabel = UILabel()` while the label already there and you are putting a new instance every time.

**Solution 1**

You have to add the subview once and reuse it by using the tag.

Declare the `let timeLabel :UILabel?`  at class level means where your all variables are declare and check its reference in the `cellForItemAt` `atIndexPath` like

```
if timeLabel == nil {
    timeLabel = UILabel()
    timeLabel.frame = cell.textView.frame
    timeLabel.text = "abc"
    timeLabel.textColor = .blue
    timeLabel.tag = 766
    cell.addSubview(timeLabel)
}
```

*And last get it with the tag* in the `cellForItemAt` `atIndexPath`

**Problem 2**

That is not in the bottom right because after `awakeFromNib()` in `JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell` this is not adding means label adds before setupLayout.

**Solution 2**

**A:** You have to add the constraint manually.

**B:** OR you can try by setting the frame at last line before returning cell.

Comment: thanks, due to your answer I understand what's wrong!

Comment: `let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 50, width: 200, height: 20))
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.textColor = .red
        
        label.tag = 200
        view.addSubview(label)` in viewDidLoad

Comment: `override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = super.collectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAt: indexPath) as! JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell
        
        let timeLabel: UILabel = view.viewWithTag(200) as! UILabel
        let message = messages[indexPath.item]
        let messageTime = self.messagesTime[indexPath.item]
        timeLabel.text = messageTime
 }` but it adds only 1 label at the top of my VC. If I add subview at cellForItemAt same result. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: thx, but this code crashes: 
http://imgur.com/a/RZNMm
http://imgur.com/a/xsX7h
http://imgur.com/a/O8UZF
http://imgur.com/a/sdw5r

Comment: but I don't open any urls, I just create label, and data which I get from parsing json is 100% correct...

Comment: that is for different post

Comment: So you have add this label in the cell class

Comment: I can share you the cell class with your modifications but monday if u can that is good

Comment: Wiill be great, I'll try to do it by myself tomorrow, but it'd be nice to recheck my code with yours, thanks in advance)

Comment: I've made something like what I want but it still not perfect. It'd be great to see your example)

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani hii need help i need to show top label date only once for particular message not for all messages how will i do that

Comment: @DilipTiwari use section of a table it will work for you!